# Second touch animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uibutton

Trying to get to grips with Xcode and seem to be making some progress over the last few weeks.

Does anyone know a way that a custom button can do a different set of animations on a second click.

So let say I have a custom button and its of Mario, when i click it he runs from the middle of the screen and out of the right hand side of the screen and then runs back in to the middle from the left of the screen, he also makes noise.

I have achieved this using this code:

```
- (IBAction)marioRunning_clicked:(id)sender
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(350.5, 456.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.00 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(-30.5, 456.0);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                        marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 456.0);
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        if(finished)  // NSLog ( @"Finished !!!!!" );
                        marioRunning.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 456.0);
                    }];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];

    marioRunning.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mario-running2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"mario-running3"],nil];

    marioRunning.imageView.animationDuration = 0.15;
    marioRunning.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 19;

    [marioRunning.imageView startAnimating];
}
```

How could I make him do a second set of animations on the next click? For example instead of running from left to right, if i tap him the second time he will Jump up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selected state of the button to decide which animation to do

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
     if(button.selected)
     {
          [self doAnimation1];
     }
     else
     {
          [self doAnimation2];
     }

     button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome and once I fitted my code in to it it worked so thank you very much. Do you know if there is a way for a 3rd animation to play or at least for the fist animation to play twice then the second animation to play?

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but here's a cool way to do what you want:

Make a subclass of `UIButton`, and let's call it `DDDMarioButton`:

```
typedef void (^DDDAnimationBlock)(UIButton *button);

@interface DDDMarioButton : UIButton

- (void)addAnimationBlockToQueue:(DDDAnimationBlock)block;

@end
```

Then in `DDDMarioButton.m`:

```
@interface DDDMarioButton ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *animationQueue;

@end

@implementation DDDMarioButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)button
{
    DDDAnimationBlock block = self.animationQueue[0];
    block(self);
    [self.animationQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)addAnimationBlockToQueue:(DDDAnimationBlock)block
{
    if(!self.animationQueue)
    {
        self.animationQueue = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    [self.animationQueue addObject:block];
}

@end
```

and then wherever you create your buttons, you add each step one by one:

```
DDDMarioButton *button = [[DDDMarioButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

[button addAnimationBlockToQueue:^(UIButton *button) {
   // perform some animation
}];

[button addAnimationBlockToQueue:^(UIButton *button) {
    // perform another animation
}];
```

And that should do it. I haven't tested this, you'll probably need some configuration, but that's pretty much the idea.

Comment: Hey moby, not that I am ungrateful to your answer on this question and I may revert to this option to perform multiple animations but I was hoping for a shorter answer that I can understand better as I am learning so the other answer was more up my street. Thanks